# show that the outcome of a probability function applied to an infinite sample space is equal to 1

Tags: probability, statistics

As I am reading through the first chapter of my mathematic statistics book, they define the probability function as having three mandatory properties. One of these properties is that if $\mathcal{C}$ is the sample space of all possible outcomes of an expirement, then $P(\mathcal{C})=1$

One of the exercises is asking me to show that this holds true for an infinite sample space, for example:

A quarter is flipped until a heads appears, and therefore the sample space is $\mathcal{C}=\{H,TH,TTH,\dots\}$.

How could I show this to be true?

A basic proof would be required, as I do not have an extensive mathematic background and this is a statistics course.

Comment: Well, simply compute $P(T^nH)$ for every $n\geqslant0$, add them... *et voilà!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(H) = p = 1 - q = 1- P(T)$.

Let $X$ be a random variable indicating the flip when $H$ occurs.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(X=i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}q^{i-1}p = \frac{p}{1-q} = \frac{p}{p} = 1$$

Comment: Ok, I'd like to walk through your proof to make sure that I understand it.

The first line says that the probability of heads on the first flip is $p$ which equals $1-q$, where $q$ is the probability of tails on the first flip.

Then, you set up the probability of the union of all outcomes as a summation. My textbook says multiplying the probability of separate experiment outcomes gives the probability of those outcomes happening in succession. Is that what you did?

Then, I'm not sure what happens algebraically to get $\frac{p}{1-q}$, but I  see how it boils down to 1 from there.

Comment: $P(X=i)$ is the probability of getting first $H$ at $i$th flip where the probability of getting $H$ at any flip is $p$ and that of $T$ is $q = 1-p$. So, $P(X=i) = P(TTTT\ldots TH) = q^{i-1}p$ i.e. for the first $i-1$ flips $T$ occurs and at the $i$th flip $H$ occurs. After that I used sum of geometric progression.

Comment: Ok, that clears it up! Had to look up the formula for a geometric series, but now I understand your proof completely!